# Testng : how to get all asserts within a test method?

Tags: testing, testng

I am trying to build a report for some tests made with **TestNG** framework. Is there any way to get all ***asserts*** used within a *test method*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, nope.  What you can do is to have your defined assertions, which you can use in your tests and which, when executed would increment some counter or get added to some collection which you can reference in your report listeners.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of TestNG allows you to create your own assertions, [details here](http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/).